# The world of non-weak*-topologies on $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metrizable space and consider $\mathcal{P}(X)$, the set of all probability measures on $X$.

Typically, the *weak*-topology* is considered on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, which is a very natural topology to consider and which leads to nice concepts such as the *Prokhorov metric* and also has the advantage that many properties that hold for $X$ also hold for  $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (for example, $X$ is separable if and only if $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is separable; see page 505 from the book *Infinite-dimensional Analysis* by Aliprantis & Border).

**Question 1:** Are there any other interesting topologies that have been considered on this space?

I'd be curious if other topologies also arise in *natural ways* and are interesting to consider. The tangentially related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21565/is-it-true-that-the-only-interesting-topologies-are-metric-topologies-and-weak-t) gives hope that in some cases other topologies might be useful (I would be interested in knowing whether there are such cases).

Probably asking for other topologies that also have some of the good structural properties that the weak*-topology has would be unrealistic ([this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359288/prokhorov-theorem-on-non-polish-spaces) shows that in a somewhat analogous case).

**Question 2:** Has $\mathcal{P}(X)$ also been studied as a measurable / measure space (taking the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of sets that are open w.r.t. the weak*-topology is probably the most natural think)?

Comment: For metrizable $X$, the $*$-weak topology on $P(X)$ coincides with the topology generated by the subbase consisting the sets $\{\mu\in P(X):\mu(U)>a\}$ where $U$ runs over open subsets of $X$ and $a$ over real number. It seems that for non-Tychonoff spaces, those two topologies are distinct.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thanks a lof for this insight! Hm, but when are spaces non-Tychonoff? It seems to me that that is also a pretty natural thing to require in many applications.

Comment: More interestingly, would you know anything related to the second question? I'd be happy even for the tinies bit of information.

Comment: The dependence between Borel complexity of $X$ and the Borel complexity of $P(X)$ has been studied for sure, and if I remember properly, the construction of $P(X)$ preserves the multiplicative Borel class. Also for every coanalytic space $X$ its probablity measure space $P(X)$ is coanalytic and under suitable Determinacy Axioms the construction of $P(X)$ preserves the classes $\Pi^1_n$. Some information on this topic can be found in Kechris' "Classical Descriptive Set Theory".